# Best way to rewrite an url with a varying number of parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

What is the best way to rewrite an url with a varying number of parameters?

For example I can have something like this:

> http://www.mywebsite.com/

followed by

> http://www.mywebsite.com/watches/

followed by

> http://www.mywebsite.com/watches/tissot/

followed by

> http://www.mywebsite.com/watches/tissot/cronograph/automatic/

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is a simple hierarchy then this will work.  But that's probably not how the data will go.  So you might want to use some parameters.  Like type={automatic|manual}
make={tissot|blah|...} model={cronograph|blah|...}  and get http://www.mywebsite.com/watches?type=automatic&make=tissot&module=cronograph

I suppose model numbers might be unique so you can do:
http://www.mywebsite.com/model/tissot12345

Comment: I'm not sure of the order of the elements after /watches/tissot/. The user can select the filters in any order.

Answer (score 0):

Some use hyphens (Amazon, Ebay), some use slashes (Apple). Both will be acceptable in search engines. The slashes require that you have a well-defined category/attribute system for your products.

More recent online stores like Diesel and Microsoft use slashes, but only to present the products in certain category. Becareful with fully-friendly URLs: the operation in the database query to find the product will be much costly, it will be better to have the product ID somewhere in the URL. Examples:

http://store.apple.com/br/product/MC839ZM/B?fnode=MTY1NDA0NA
http://store.diesel.com/item/detail/tskay/C569C0A4/cod10/36244178LF/mm/125

C ya!